# Formatting pen drive

Tags: usb-drive, disk-formatting

I am unable to format my pen drive. The error being displayed is:

> Error formatting volume
> Error creating file system: Command-line `mkntfs -f -F -L 'Uni''/dev/sdd" exited with non-zero exit status 1:
> stdout: `Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
> Creating NTFS volume structures.
> '
> stderr:`dev/sdd is entire device, not just one partition.
> mkntfs forced anyway.
> Error writing to /dev/sdd: No space left on device
> Error writing non-resident attribute value.
> add_attr_data_positioned failed: No space left on device
> Couldn't create $LogFile: No space left on device
> Failed to fsync device /dev/sdd: Input/output error
> Warning: Could not close /dev/sdd: Input/output error
> '(udisks-error-quark, 0)

[image: Screenshot of error in Disks app]

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Your graphioc appears to show you trying to format the CD/DVD drive which won't work. Please [edit] your question with details of the steps taken and your version of ubuntu

Comment: Actually after this error msg graphic appears CD/DVD drive selection, but I've tried for USB formatting only, it is visible in dialogue also

Comment: Actually, the screenshot you posted pertains only to the errors from attempting to format your CD/DVD drive which appears to contain no optical media. You should edit your question and include more relevant details. Tell us exactly the steps you are taking. If you receive errors please make sure that the errors that you post are related to the task that you are having problems with. It is better if you would also copy/paste the entire error you are receiving since pictures of text are difficult to work with

Comment: You can analyze the situation according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

First check whether your dvd can be formatted (DVD-R vs DVD-RW).

If it is a formattable disk / drive , try gparted for linux :

$ sudo apt get install gparted

$ sudo gparted

For windows : Try any partition assistant free to download
( Aomei, Ease US , etc..)

Comment: I think the OP wants help to format a USB pendrive (not a DVD). But gparted is a good tool for a USB pendrive, so your advice can be relevant anyway.

Comment: Warning: It is a good idea to start graphical application programs either from the menu or when from a terminal window with elevated permissions using the option **-H**, `sudo -H GUI-app`. Otherwise there can be problems with permissions, if it is a program that can be run both with and without elevated permissions, because some settings file can be overwritten by the user `root`, so that the regular user will no longer have access to it. - gparted always runs with elevated permissions, so not affected, but `sudo -H ...` is a good habit to prevent mistakes with other programs.